# I want to add a new page for Google maps that can be marked by the users on my OpenCart site

Tags: opencart

Once the user buys an item, I want to give them a credit to mark on the Google map page on the website along with a message.
How can I implement it?
It would be really great if I could do it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have any code for this, and if so what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?